# CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics"

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, react-native, cocoapods

I'm new to React-Native and developing a project. Previously, it was working fine but when I installed Push Notification (rnfirebase for messaging) related dependencies, I'm getting these errors and I also tried all possible solutions from other questions too but no success.

Here is the complete errors which I'm getting while pod installation.

```
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
  In snapshot (Podfile.lock):
    Firebase/Analytics (= 6.13.0)

  In Podfile:
    Firebase/Analytics

RNFBMessaging (from `../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/messaging`) was resolved to 7.1.5, which depends on
  Firebase/Analytics (~> 6.25.0)


You have either:
 * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
 * changed the constraints of dependency `Firebase/Analytics` inside your development pod `RNFBMessaging`.
   You should run `pod update Firebase/Analytics` to apply changes you've made.
```

This is the code in the pod file.

```
# add the Firebase pod for Google Analytics
  pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
  # pod 'Firebase/Auth'
  pod 'Fabric', '~> 1.10.2'
  pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.14.0'
  # add pods for any other desired Firebase products
  # https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#available-pods
```

I tried the following workaround to resolve this issue.

```
1. pod install --repo-update

2. pod repo remove master 
   pod setup 
   pod install

3. Delete podfile.lock
   pod install
```

But none solution worked for me. Can anyone please help me to resolve this issue? I will really appreciate it.

Comment: can you show your pod file?. I think you are mentioning version for FirBase Analytic pod in your pod file

Comment: I have updated question regarding pods.

Comment: have you mentioned a specific version for RNFBMessaging? well the Firebase Analytics pod installed automatically is versioned 6.13.0 but the pod RNFBMessaging(which has Firebase analytics as a dependency) requires Firebase Analytics version greater than 6.25.0. Please  try mentioning pod 'Firebase/Analytics', '~> 6.25.0' and check if that fixes the issue

Comment: Unfortunately, it not helped

Comment: The answers are in the error message and above. Please share the Podfile and it will be possible to provide a more precise solution.

Comment: Usually you pick Fabric OR Crashlytics - they do the same thing and could conflict each other.